# Speeding up numpy small function

Tags: python, performance, numpy, optimization, scipy

This small function is called multiple times in an application and runs really slow compared to the same code implementation in Matlab. There it works maybe as much as 10-100 times faster in so I was wondering where can it be improved in python/numpy.

```
def ahamming(n,mid):
    data = np.zeros(n)
    wid1 = mid - 1
    wid2 = n - mid
    wid = max(wid1,wid2)

    for i in range(n):
        arg = (i+1) - mid;
        data[i] = np.cos((np.pi*arg)/wid);
    return 0.54 + 0.46*data
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is an easy one for vectorization. The good thing when working with numpy arrays is that you can avoid loops and make use of numpy's speed.

You can substitute the loop as follows:

```
def ahamming(n,mid):
    data = np.zeros(n)
    wid1 = mid - 1
    wid2 = n - mid
    wid = max(wid1,wid2)

    i = np.arange(n)
    arg = (i+1) - mid
    data = 0.54 + 0.46*np.cos((np.pi*arg)/wid)

    return data
```

Slightly more efficient, but maybe less intuitive is

```
i = np.arange(1, n+1)
arg = i - mid
```

Edit: Speed results are in. Your loop-version with n = 500 takes 3.97 sec for 10000 calculations. The numpy version tool 0.10 sec which is faster by factor 40.

Comment: Thanks I just found out that the np.cos function can work on the whole array and is much, much faster.

Comment: Also, fixed the missing part. As this was simple I am not sure if I should delete the question now.

Comment: That's the whole point of numpy. Any arithmetic is always performed on the whole array. That's why `i+1` works when `i` is an array. It would not if it were a list.

Answer (score 2):

Numpy [implementation](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.17.0/numpy/lib/function_base.py#L2860-L2957) can offer some hints from [docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.hamming.html).

```py
## reference numpy implementation linked above
def hamming(M):
    if M < 1:
        return array([])
    if M == 1:
        return ones(1, float)
    n = arange(0, M)
    return 0.54 - 0.46*cos(2.0*pi*n/(M-1)) # of importance
```